# Stop apex from displaying label in apex:pageblocksection

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblock, pageblocksection

Can we stop apex from outputting labels for apex:outputText within a pageblocksection?
I have a html table on which I only want to input text field, i.e. without any labels. But the rendered code is displaying labels and I can't seem to stop it from doing that. Example code:

```
            <apex:pageblockSection  collapsible="true"  columns="1" title="Client Needs Mapping"   >

                <table >
                    <thead>
                        <th>Client Needs</th>   
                         <th>Column 2</th>                         
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr> 
                            <td><apex:inputText value="{!Opportunity.customField1}" /></td>
                            <td><apex:inputText value="Opportunity.customField2"</td>
                        </tr></tbody>
                </table>

            </apex:pageblockSection>
```

The rendered html not only contains the text field but its label as well, hence getting my table format messed up.

NOTE: I cannot use pageblocktable or anyother buit-in grid/table etc.. 
Any help is much much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try setting the label attribute of [apex:inputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputText.htm)?

Comment: It worked. Pretty straight forward too! What a stupid question. lol. Please post it as an answer so I can select it. Thanks!

Comment: @BarCotter Using Label="" solves the issue on hiding label. But the whole table gets messed up even more. Please take a look at the sceenshot: http://s30.postimg.org/4os5hdc9d/sfdc.png Thank you for all the help here.

Answer (score 0):

Use apex:pageBlockSectionItem to display the field. Should work!

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.customField1}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I need to display far complex structure in a table. This will only render text fields. Any idea how to implement fields in a html table?

Comment: Have you tried attribute label="" in your field tags?

Comment: Please see my comment about using Label="". Thanks